# Is there any way to refresh a tab in Android?

Tags: android

I have two tabs. When I change a value in the first tab, another value in the second tab also should change depending on the change in the first tab. How to do it?. Please help at the earliest?. Or Is it possible to load the second tab once more.. any refreshment mechanism?

Comment: Please refer this link. It will help you a lot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436035/wanted-an-example-which-uses-onresume-on-start-and-on-restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `onResume()` function and add the code to load the tab again here.