# Tabs are not getting refreshed

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, android-widget

I have 2 tabs namely Insert and Display in my application.

As soon as I insert records in the 1st tab its shows me Message : "INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY"
But when I saw 2nd Tab it showed me only OLD DATA  - new Inserted Data was not Visible"

then I identified that my 2nd tab was not getting Refreshed.

So how to refresh the tabs dynamically through coding. ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards :)

Comment: use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag

Comment: @JaiSoni  How to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  ??

Comment: @Rushabh hi..How r u...we r classemate in bca .....please try this code after complitation Call notifyDataSetChanged() .

Comment: hii m fine. thanks for the help @ChiragPatel.. 

do I need to write notifyDataSetChanged in Button Click.. ?

Comment: @Rushabh check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113995/is-there-any-way-to-refresh-a-tab-in-android

Comment: @JaiSoni i had tried onResume method which was answered in above link..